# Cassandra configuration: difference between write_request_timeout_in_ms and counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms

Tags: cassandra

In Apache Cassandra's configuration file (cassandra.yaml), I want to know the difference between the two following configuration attributes:

## How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete

`write_request_timeout_in_ms`: 2000

## How long the coordinator should wait for counter writes to complete

`counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms`: 5000

I don't find any information about the `counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms` attribute.

JimyRyan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`write_request_timeout_in_ms` is write timeout for normal tables.

`counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms` is write timeout for tables with counter columns.

All `counter_*` related settings in `cassandra.yaml` are for counter tables.

[CASSANDRA-8878](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8878?focusedCommentId=14346748&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14346748)

Answer (score 1):

`write_request_timeout_in_ms` is used for regular column writes. 
`counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms` is used for counter columns.

Have a look at here for counter columns: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html